# How to do 3d barcharts in latex using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, bar-chart

I wanted to do a barchart for annual report. I have made it in excel
[image]

There are so many problems of using this in latex as it is since I dont want any backgroud for this. In the sense that it has to fit with background which I am using section wise in my document wherever I placed.(note sometimes the section may differ).

So, I thought of doing this graph in latex itself which will give more control on it.

### How to do that?

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you

Comment: [opinion-based comment] I'd say: **don't**. 3D bar-charts lead to [reading-bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misleading_graph#3D), and "[*less is more*](http://www.treesmapsandtheorems.com/pdfs/TM&Th-4.0-summary.pdf)" (since 3D do not bring additional information, it is just noise that blurs the information you want to deliver to the reader).

Comment: I agree with you but when you are going for colourful reports these things are attractive. @ebo

Comment: Concur on "reading-bias", but I would use knitr (R) and LaTeX together to create such graphics. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794236/ggplot2-3d-bar-plot  example of R code.  Normally, I would create a full example as an answer, but currently I am very booked with other projects.

Comment: @David : see http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30701248#30701248 for more info (and for not polluting this comment section) `(-:`